# cocos2dx3.3 camera doesn't move with sprite

Tags: lua, camera, cocos2d-x

I am trying to use cocos2dx 3.3 to build games.

we create a physicisworld with

```
cc.Scene:createWithPhysics()
```

and i add a camera like this

```
local camera = cc.Camera:createOrthographic(width,height,0,1)
camera:setCameraFlag(cc.CameraFlag.USER1)
camera:setPosition3D(cc.vec3(0, 0, 0))
```

and I add this camera to the layer
I just want to bind the sprite with camera
so I code in layer function update

```
function PlayLayer:update(delta)
   --camera
   local camera = self.camera

   local speed = 100*delta

   local winsize = cc.Director:getInstance():getWinSize()
   local player = self.player
   player:update()

   player:setX(player:getX() + speed)
   local postiony = 180

   self.camera:setPositionX(player:getX() )
end
```

I set the camera move with sprite，however the sprite is moving and the position of camera is also changed. but, there is no effect. the sprite just move out of the screen.
Am I wrong. please help me with this question. thank you!